# How can I change the html title of my main.hbs file from a partial.hbs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to change my html title depending on the partial that I load for the body.

Parent html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            {{title}}
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{>body}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Partial body.hbs file:

```
<h1 id="brick-mason">Brick Mason</h1>
<h3 id="what-is-a-brick-mason-">What is a brick mason?</h3>
<p>Brick masons use various stones, concrete and bricks to build walls, walkways, fences, and other structures.</p>
```

What can I change so that my partial can determine what the `title` on my main html page displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was including a second partial in the handlebars file and then splitting them out in the grunt file config.

gruntfile.js

```
file_context: function(src) {
    var fileName = path.basename(src).split(".")[0];
    var obj = glob.route[fileName];

    var fileString = fs.readFileSync("./" + src, "utf8").split("<split />");

    return {
        partials: {
            header: fileString[0] || "",
            body: fileString[1] || "",
        },
        src: 'src/base.hbs',
        dest: path.join('static', obj, 'index.html')
    };
}
```

base.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.min.css" />
        {{>header}}

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav_background"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="nav_bar">
                <div class="nav left_nav">
                    <a href="/" class="nav_text right_text">BlueCollarJobs101</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav right_nav">
                    <a href="{{route.states}}" class="nav_text right_text">States</a>
                    <a href="{{route.jobs}}" class="nav_text right_text">Jobs</a>
                    <a href="{{route.contact-us}}" class="nav_text right_text">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="markdown-body">
                {{>body}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it easily with JavaScript,

just add in the `body.hbs` :

```
<script> document.title = 'the title here ' </script>
```

Comment: What kind of impact does changing the title through javascript have on SEO?

Answer (score 0):

In your Partial.hbs body add the script to manipulate the  tags

```
<h1 id="brick-mason">Brick Mason</h1>
<h3 id="what-is-a-brick-mason-">What is a brick mason?</h3>
<p>Brick masons use various stones, concrete and bricks to build walls, walkways, fences, and other structures.</p>
<script>
    const title = document.querySelector('title');
    title.innerHTML = 'Partial';
</script>
```